# Protect access to files and folders via url

Tags: php, security, .htaccess

In my .htaccess file, I am using the below to prevent direct access to folders:

```
Options -Indexes
```

I am using the below to prevent access to a critical file of ours:

```
<Files admin.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from (my ipaddress)
</Files>
```

So, now users cant go to www.domain.com/scripts as it throw 404 error, nor can they access admin.php

But how do I prevent direct access to all?

For example, if someone knew the filename, they can still get to it, such as: www.domain.com/scripts/process.php

What to do?

Comment: It seems like you should simply move the directory outside the document root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using mod_rewrite:**

Put this rule on top of all other rules:

```
RewriteRule ^scripts(/.*|)$ - [F,NC]
```

**Without using mod_rewrite:**

Put this code in `scripts/.htaccess`:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

**UPDATE:** To block direct access to all files:

```
# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \..+[\s?]
# return forbidden error if not static files
RewriteRule (?!^.+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$)^.*$ - [F]
```

Comment: I am trying to prevent access to all files (/scripts) was just an example. Tried RewriteRule ^(/.*|)$ - [F,NC] but its still allowing access to files.

Comment: Are you trying to block direct access to all the files?

Comment: yes, for example: domain.com/home = okay, domain.com/home/file.php not okay

Comment: ty, it works. I was previously using #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f and #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d What does the "!" do? And when is -d needed?

Comment: the fix created a new issue. mys style sheets and some links are no longer working?

Comment: Yes css/js/image would be impacted since we blocked access to all the files. Are these files being served from same subdirectory like `/static/...` then we can add an exception in above rule. Last resort is to create exception using file extensions like `.js, .css, .jpeg, .png, .gif, .png` etc.